# Mail into GMail spam folder, SPF and everyting passes

Tags: email, gmail, spam, spf

My mails that I send from my vps keeps going to the spam folder of Google mail (gmail), **only gmail**, all other receivers get the mail!

I've been struggling with the following problem for a couple of hours now.
First of all the mail went straight to the spam, with a soft fail on the SPF records. After some googling and adjusting the dns and everything is correct on all the tests I do on internet.

What am I doing wrong, see the email headers below:

```
Delivered-To: info@MYWEBSITE.nl
Received: by 10.140.49.2 with SMTP id p2csp254884qga;
        Wed, 18 Dec 2013 05:09:01 -0800 (PST)
X-Received: by 10.180.103.193 with SMTP id fy1mr8266239wib.10.1387372141146;
        Wed, 18 Dec 2013 05:09:01 -0800 (PST)
Return-Path: <info@SENDINGWEBSITE.nl>
Received: from www.SENDINGVPS.nl ([2a02:1234::777:3eff:fed6:7ef6])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id s9si717710wiw.41.2013.12.18.05.09.00
        for <info@MYWEBSITE.nl>
        (version=TLSv1 cipher=RC4-SHA bits=128/128);
        Wed, 18 Dec 2013 05:09:01 -0800 (PST)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of info@SENDINGWEBSITE.nl designates 2a02:1234::777:3eff:fed6:7ef6 as permitted sender) client-ip=2a02:1234::777:3eff:fed6:7ef6;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of info@SENDINGWEBSITE.nl designates 2a02:1234::777:3eff:fed6:7ef6 as permitted sender) smtp.mail=info@SENDINGWEBSITE.nl
Received: from i12345.upc-i.chello.nl ([62.195.XX.XXX] helo=[192.168.1.12])
    by www.SENDINGVPS.nl with esmtpsa (TLSv1:AES128-SHA:128)
    (Exim 4.76)
    (envelope-from <info@SENDINGWEBSITE.nl>)
    id 1VtGrz-0004Rq-8k; Wed, 18 Dec 2013 14:08:59 +0100
Subject: Mail gmail hotmail
Mime-Version: 1.0 (1.0)
From: "info@SENDINGWEBSITE.nl" <info@SENDINGWEBSITE.nl>
Content-Type: text/plain;
    charset=us-ascii
X-Mailer: iPhone Mail (11B554a)
Message-Id: <62D8B201-8243-43A5-B15D-6371DD208D23@SENDINGWEBSITE.nl>
Date: Wed, 18 Dec 2013 14:08:58 +0100
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
To: "info@MYWEBSITE.nl" <info@MYWEBSITE.nl>

Hi

Verstuurd vanaf mijn iPhone
```

Comment: hard to tell with all hostnames/ips munged. Many providers add strict checks especially on IPv6 mail delivery. make sure your sending ip6 has both [forward confirmed reverse DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward-confirmed_reverse_DNS) and a **non-generic** HELO in **your own domain** (not _vps1337.yourvpsprovier.com_ )

Comment: ok thanks I will have a look at that

Comment: @Gryphius How do you change the non-generic HELO for a domain?

Comment: MTAs use the configured hostname as HELO by default. Set this to a resolvable FQDN in a domain under your control.

Comment: @Gryphius how do I do this?